# В отчаянье? Или в отчаяньи?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

Стихотворение Виславы Шимборской «Кот в пустой квартире» много раз переводили на русский язык. Вот один из переводов: https://stihi.ru/2009/07/27/1499
В четвертой строке второй строфы, по-моему, ошибка. Или две.

А мне что делать там, где мы вдвоём
С тобой, хозяин, вместе обитали?
Гляжу на мир я сквозь окна проём
В отчаянье и грусти, и печали.

Наверно, нужно было написать «В отчаяньи»? И не нужна ли после «В отчаяньи» запятая? Хотя это вряд ли…

Так что, видимо, строфа должна выглядеть так:

А мне что делать там, где мы вдвоём
С тобой, хозяин, вместе обитали?
Гляжу на мир я сквозь окна проём
В отчаяньи и грусти, и печали.

Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ОТВЕТ**

*А мне что делать там, где мы вдвоём*

*С тобой, хозяин, вместе обитали?*

*Гляжу на мир я сквозь окна проём*

***В отчаянье, и грусти, и печали.***

***В отчаянье*** – нейтральный (общеупотребительный) вариант, ***в отчаяньи*** – допустимый вариант.

Из словаря: **ОТЧАЯНИЕ; ОТЧАЯНЬЕ**,  ср. Состояние крайней безнадёжности, безвыходности. Прийти, впасть в о. Приводить, привести в о. кого-л. Рыдать от отчаяния.

**ПРАВИЛО (ответ справочной службы русского языка)**

**Слова среднего рода на  ИЕ**  имеют в предложном падеже, в отступление от общего правила, окончание  И, а не Е : в сопровождении, в молчании, в подразделении. Слова среднего рода на ЬЕ имеют в предложном падеже окончание  Е: ***в ущелье, о варенье.***

У большого количества слов есть **вариантные формы** на ИЕ и на ЬЕ, например:  спасение – спасенье, молчание – молчанье и т. п. При этом формы на ИЕ часто (но не всегда) являются общеупотребительными и стилистически нейтральными, а формы на ЬЕ характерны для разговорной и поэтической речи.

При наличии таких вариантов на ИЕ и ЬЕ указанные падежные формы имеют разные окончания И и  Е, например: ***об умении – об уменье, в молчании –в молчанье.***

Однако в художественной, особенно поэтической, речи допускается  написание форм предложного падежа существительных среднего рода на ЬЕ (обычно при предлоге В) с окончанием И, например: ***В молчаньи*** шел один ты с мыслию великой (Пушкин). Ошибкой здесь это не является.

См.: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина. М., 2006 (и более поздние издания).